# How to get condensed logging 'spring style'

Tags: java, logging

Our logs, like most logs, get a bit verbose and most of that noise includes the fqcn of the class that did the logging.

I would like to have it log just the first letter of each package/subpackage until it gets to the class.

Example

```
com.mycompany.client.magensa.MockMagensaClient
```

Under normal circumstances this would log as:

```
c.v.c.m.MockMagensaClient
```

I can obviously write a custom logger but I am certain there is one I can already use. As I don't even know what this style is I am at a loss for what I am even looking for.

Anyone just wanna say: "Oh, you're looking at ... and you can find it ..."?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are familiar with log4j I would use use logback:

http://logback.qos.ch/

http://logback.qos.ch/manual/layouts.html#conversionWord

**EDIT**:

Apparently also supported in log4j:

http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/EnhancedPatternLayout.html

Comment: This is very good. Could you put an example pattern for log4j? I will start using it in future projects.

Comment: Hi Paul, both links have example patterns specified.

Comment: There is not an example of short style in log4j. Thanks for the help.

Comment: %c{1.} org.apache.commons.Foo results in o.a.c.Foo

Comment: EnhancedPatternLayout worked for me. 

log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.EnhancedPatternLayout