# Extract the first letter after a slash '/' and the last whole word

Tags: regex, sed

So, I have this string:

`JobDefinition://apps/ess/scm/productHub/itemImport/ItemImportSchedulingJobDef`

And I want to transform it to:

`/a/e/s/p/i/ItemImportSchedulingJobDef`

When I use: `sed -E 's|/([a-z]{1})|\1|g'`

I just get

`JobDefinition:/appsessscmproductHubitemImport/ItemImportSchedulingJobDef`
I am using sed, but I think this is a general regex question.

It's basically a namespacing and it's very long, so I am trying to maintain something of the namespace and the final unique identifier

It's very similar to [springs condensed logging for fully qualified class names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18769569/how-to-get-condensed-logging-spring-style) (my inspiration)

Comment: Do you care about the `JobDefinition://` part ?

Comment: Regarding `I think this is a general regex question` - there is no such thing as a general regex. There are BREs, EREs, PCREs, and more flavours of regex, and all tools that use them have their own caveats, delimiters, options, and extensions. For example `\s` will match any space in GNU awk, GNU sed, and GNU grep but not some others, and any perl. `\w` will match a letter, number or underscore in some GNU tools but not others. `\d` will match a digit in perl and GNU grep when called with `-P` but no sed or awk and no other greps, etc., etc. And that's very much just the tip of the iceberg.

Comment: I guess I meant I wasn't looking for a sed specific solution, per-se. In fact, it isn't for sed at all, that's just how I was testing it. Turns out, it works just fine in PLSQL

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use this `sed`:

```bash
s='JobDefinition://apps/ess/scm/productHub/itemImport/ItemImportSchedulingJobDef'

sed -E 's~^[^:]+:/|(/[a-z])[^/]+~\1~g' <<< "$s"

/a/e/s/p/i/ItemImportSchedulingJobDef
```

Here:

- `^[^:]+:/`: Matches initial part before & including `:/` in input
- `|`: OR
- `(/[a-z])[^/]+`: Matches `/` followed by a lowercase letter and captures it in group #1. Then it matches 1+ of any characters that are not `/`.
- In the substitution we put back back-reference of 1st capture group i.e. `\1`

However, this assumes that last part always starts with non lower case letter.

If that's not the case you may use this `sed` command with a loop:

```bash
sed -E -e 's~^[^:]+:/~~' -e :a -e 's~(/[a-zA-Z])[^/]+/~\1/~g; ta' <<< "$s"

/a/e/s/p/i/ItemImportSchedulingJobDef
```

Comment: I was looking for a single regex solution, But I guess I didn't specify that.

Comment: I have updated the answer (1st command) to make it single regex with alternation.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E ':a;s#(^.*:/|(/.)[^/]+)/#\2/#;ta' file
```

Remove upto and including the first `:/`.

Then  remove all characters between `/.../` and replace them by `/` and the following character.

This can be achieved in a loop which uses a substitution command with alternation and back references.